# How is x←y spoken in the context of linked lists?

Tags: math, linked-list

In Donald Knuth's paper, [Dancing Links](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0011047.pdf), Knuth uses the "← "operator to describe updates applied to links of a doubly linked list.  How is this operator spoken?

#### How I think this might be spoken:

L[R[x]] ← L[x]

```
L[R[x]] (now) points to L[x]
```

#### In further detail:

L[R[x]]

```
The pointer to the predecessor of the successor of x
```

←

```
points to
```

L[x]

```
the predecessor of x
```

I consulted Wikipedia's [List of mathematical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols), but the uses of arrows described there seem to consist of implication and function mapping.

Thinking this use of "←" might be domain-specific, I skimmed [this paper](http://www.mit.edu/~kkz/ZeeKuncakRinardPLDI08.pdf) on linked lists.  However it uses "←" in the mathematical sense to mean "implies".

Comment: Great question. It appears that the arrow is an assignment operator, in which case it might be read as "gets", e.g. "L[R[x]] gets L[x]". About expanding that, I would say "L[R[x]] now points to the same place as L[x]", not "... points to L[x]", because (I believe) L[x] is a so-called L-value, which means specifically that it's own value is a location or pointer, and not a general value. Hope that makes sense. Not sure where to ask for more clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From "The Art of Computer Programming" pg.3 : "The arrow  "←" in step E3 is the all-important *replacement* operation, sometimes called *assignment* or *substitution*." The usual way  `n←m` is spoken would be "n set to m", although this has an imperative programming flavor.